# PHP/MYSQL: populating a table by column

Tags: php, mysql, database

My code is currently this:

```
if (isset($_POST['viewstudentdrop'])) {
    $query = "SELECT students.*, lessons.lessonname 
            FROM lessons INNER JOIN 
            (assignments INNER JOIN students 
            ON assignments.studentid = students.id) 
            ON lessons.lessonid = assignments.lesson
            WHERE (((students.id)=".$_POST['viewstudentdrop']."))";
    $results = $pdodl->query($query);
    while ($row = $results->fetch()) {
            echo "<p>Lesson: ". $row['lessonname'] . "</p>";
    }
   // View Completed Lessons and Times
    $query = "SELECT * 
            FROM studentresponse 
            WHERE studentid = ".$_POST['viewstudentdrop']." 
            ORDER BY lessonsession";
    $results = $pdodl->query($query);
    echo '<table> ';
    while ($row = $results->fetch()) {
    echo '<tr> <td> ' . $row['actiontime'] .'</td>' .
                     ' <td> ' . $row['page'] .'</td>' .
                     ' <td> ' . $row['response'] . '</td>'.
                     ' <td> '. $row['lessonsession'] . '<td> </tr>';
    }
    echo  '</table>';  
}
```

It results in output like this:

```
19:40:44     sda02   C   11360611641    
19:40:46     sda03   D   11360611641    
19:40:50     sda04   3   11360611641    
19:40:53     sda05   A   11360611641    
19:41:22     sda02   B   11360611678    
19:41:24     sda03   C   11360611678    
19:41:31     sda04   5   11360611678    
19:41:34     sda05   B   11360611678    
20:00:39     sda02   B   11360612836    
20:00:41     sda03   C   11360612836    
20:00:44     sda04   3   11360612836    
20:00:47     sda05   B   11360612836
```

I can output the data as it is formatted above to a table straight from the database, but I would like to output it as tables such as (broken by lessonsession):

```
sda02     sda03     sda04     sda05
19:40:44  19:40:46  19:40:50  19:40:53
C         D         3         A

sda02     sda03     sda04     sda05
19:41:22  19:41:24  19:41:31  19:41:34
B         C         5         B
```

.... and so on for the next lessonsession group.

May have been confusing before. Hope this helps clarify my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Why store / duplicate the data instead of a sophisticated `SELECT`?

Comment: What is an example of a sophisticated select? I have only used "Select * from 'studentresponse' where 'userid' = 8 (for example).

Comment: @ChrisWilson what are the column headers on the result?

Comment: 'id', 'userid', 'actiontime', 'page', 'response', 'lessonsession'.

Comment: Is there a static list of possible values for `page`, or is that list dynamic and possibly changing in the future?  i.e., can we assume they will always be one of `sda01`, `sda02`, `sda03`, `sda04`, `rwr01`, `rwr02`, `someother`, `someother2`, etc?

Comment: pages are static. They are existing pages from another table. When the student "completes" a page (by answering it as shown in the response", the record is written to this table (above). HOWEVER, some lessons will have more pages (like sda01 through sda19), and other lessons might be dds01 through dds45.

Comment: @ChrisWilson I don't understand what data you want each column, can you edit your OP with more details?

Comment: Done. Added original code and output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really ugly way to do this in SQL.

This answer implements user defined variables to generate a row number for each row, this is then used to *unpivot* the data into columns. Lastly, an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression is used to rotate the data back into columns.

```
select col,
  lessonsession,
  max(case when rn = 1 then value end) Col1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then value end) Col2,
  max(case when rn = 3 then value end) Col3,
  max(case when rn = 4 then value end) Col4
from
(
  select 'actiontime' col, actiontime value, lessonsession, rn
  from 
  (
    select actiontime,
      page, 
      response, 
      lessonsession,
      @row:=case when @prev=lessonsession then @row else 0 end +1 rn,
      @prev:=lessonsession
    from yourtable
    cross join (select @row:=0, @prev:=null) r
    order by lessonsession
  ) s
  union all
  select 'page' col, page value, lessonsession, rn
  from
  (
    select actiontime,
      page, 
      response, 
      lessonsession,
      @row:=case when @prev=lessonsession then @row else 0 end +1 rn,
      @prev:=lessonsession
    from yourtable
    cross join (select @row:=0, @prev:=null) r
    order by lessonsession
  ) s
  union all
  select 'response' col, response value, lessonsession, rn
  from 
  (
    select actiontime,
      page, 
      response, 
      lessonsession,
      @row:=case when @prev=lessonsession then @row else 0 end +1 rn,
      @prev:=lessonsession
    from yourtable
    cross join (select @row:=0, @prev:=null) r
    order by lessonsession
  ) s
) src
group by col, lessonsession
order by lessonsession, col
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f840/11).

This gives the result:

```
|        COL | LESSONSESSION |     COL1 |     COL2 |     COL3 |     COL4 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| actiontime |   11360611641 | 19:40:44 | 19:40:46 | 19:40:50 | 19:40:53 |
|       page |   11360611641 |    sda02 |    sda03 |    sda04 |    sda05 |
|   response |   11360611641 |        C |        D |        3 |        A |
| actiontime |   11360611678 | 19:41:34 | 19:41:31 | 19:41:24 | 19:41:22 |
|       page |   11360611678 |    sda05 |    sda04 |    sda03 |    sda02 |
|   response |   11360611678 |        B |        5 |        C |        B |
| actiontime |   11360612836 | 20:00:39 | 20:00:41 | 20:00:44 | 20:00:47 |
|       page |   11360612836 |    sda02 |    sda03 |    sda04 |    sda05 |
|   response |   11360612836 |        B |        C |        3 |        B |
```

One thing that you can do to easily clean this up is to use a temp table for the records once the row number is applied. Inserting the following into a temp table, would make the code shorter without so much repetition:

```
select actiontime,
  page, 
  response, 
  lessonsession,
  @row:=case when @prev=lessonsession then @row else 0 end +1 rn,
  @prev:=lessonsession
from yourtable
cross join (select @row:=0, @prev:=null) r
order by lessonsession
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay... I've managed to muddle through my original thought of using arrays to reorganize the data on the page.

Here's the code (picked up from the second query):

```
    $query = "SELECT * 
            FROM studentresponse 
            WHERE studentid = ".$_POST['viewstudentdrop']." 
            ORDER BY lessonsession";
    $results = $pdodl->query($query);
    while ($row = $results->fetch()) { 
        $iteration[] = array ($row['page'], $row['actiontime'], $row['response'], $row['lessonsession']);
        }
    //Rewrite the data using the array into the format I want
    $x=0; $y=0;
    echo '<table>';
    while (isset($iteration[$x][$y]))  {
        echo '<tr>';        
        while (isset($iteration[$x][$y])) {
            echo '<td>' . $iteration[$x][$y] . '</td>';
            $x++;
        }
        echo '</tr>';
        $x = 0;
        $y++;
}
    echo '</table>';
```

This produces the following:
[image]
Now, all I have to do is break the table for each change in 'lessonsession'.

(I'm really feeling like a programmer now - I want to terminate sentences with a semicolon.)